# How to run database content checking on choosing dropdown

Tags: database, wordpress

please ignore grammar mistakes.

My company website has a search form. I need to adjust the content on the dropdown according to the selection made on the first dropdowns. is it possible to do on a WordPress website? if possible how can I do that?
you can check my company website here : https://highmarkuae.com/

I am talking about the first form on the homepage

 Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Is it possible" - yes. Probably you need to write some code about this

Comment: Yes, could you share your efforts.